# Best way to get identity of updated row in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, triggers, timestamp

What is the best way to get identity of updated row in Oracle? I am trying to write a trigger which is able to update a timestamp field in each updated row in table Customer.

my table:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER 
(
  ID NUMBER NOT NULL 
, LASTNAME NVARCHAR2(20) 
, FIRSTNAME NVARCHAR2(20) 
, UPDATETS TIMESTAMP(30) NOT NULL 
, UPDATEUSER VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_PK PRIMARY KEY 
(
    ID 
  )
);
```

my Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPDATETS_REG_TRG 
AFTER UPDATE ON CUSTOMER 
REFERENCING OLD AS oldAlias
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  if updating then
    update CUSTOMER 
      set UPDATETS = SYSTIMESTAMP, UPDATEUSER = User where CUSTOMER.ID = oldAlias.ROWID ;
  end if;    
END;
```

I am getting this error: Fehler(8,78):

```
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "OLDALIAS"."ROWID": invalid identifier
```

Can someone please help me on this issue? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need a `before` trigger and you'd just modify attributes in the `:new` pseudorecord

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPDATETS_REG_TRG 
  BEFORE UPDATE ON CUSTOMER 
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  :new.updateTS := systimestamp;
  :new.updateUser := user;
END;
```

Comment: @sead4711 - Yes.  The trigger is called once (at least) for each row that is updated.  The modifications you make to the `:new` pseudorecord are made for just that one row.

Comment: Thanks Justin :) That was the perfect answer :)